# Insert content in object

Tags: jquery, object

I have some navigation like so:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want when i click on a link the content of that page to be insertet in an object. I've tried

```
$('nav ul li a').click( function() {

    var obj={};

    $(this).nextAll('.content').insertAfter(obj);

});
```

In other words im trying to cache that content in the object so later if i want to do something i want to search in the object. I hope my question is asked correctly :)

Comment: You'd better show the complete code

Comment: @solenoo: Is the above code working?? Since the selector `$('nav ul li a')` is invalid. It should be `$('.nav ul li a')`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you know what javascript objects actually are? They can't be inserted into DOM like that, nor does calling `obj = {}` actually load anything from anywhere.

From what I understand, you're attempting to load page content via AJAX. If that's the case, I'd suggest you take a look at jQuery's [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$('nav ul li a').click( function() {
    var location = $(this).attr("href"); // get the location of the link
    $.get(location, function(data){ // call AJAX to load the page content
         $("#content").html(data); // put page content into #content
    });
    return false; // make sure the link doesn't then follow through
});
```

Comment: yeah thats what im triying to do, the problem is that i dont know how to store the content i've loaded in an object.

Comment: I've included an example on how to use `.get()`. Why do you want to store page content into an object anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to cache it so later on it doesnt search through the whole dom but only loads it from the object, im not sure if that made any sense to you

Comment: But when loading via AJAX, jQuery caches it for you. So even if you call `.get()` on every click, if the content was loaded previously, it will use the old cache. Not to mention, I don't know what "search through the whole DOM" means here, as content of other pages isn't part of the current page's DOM before you append it in there. I don't see any reason to use this object approach.

Comment: I edited the answer to contain everything you need to load page content via AJAX. Unless you have some other purpose in mind, I can't recommend saving anything into objects.

Comment: let me explain it this way. when i open my console in FF and when i click on a page i want it to show GET........ only once i dont want:

GET.....
GET.....

No matter how many times i click on the same page i want the GET.... to be shown only once

Comment: Why do you think the amount of GET requests matters? Loading the entire site on first entry into an object is not very advisable; not to mention, you'd still have a GET request for each page separately, so realistically what you're achieving is more GET requests, not less, and most of them in vain, as not every user visits every page. What is the purpose of such a system? If you really want the whole site to load at once, put each page into its own div, and use `.hide()` and `.show()` to display the correct div when links are clicked.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger: Is the above code working?? Since the selector `$('nav ul li a')` is invalid. It should be `$('.nav ul li a')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the content using [**.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like:

```
$('.nav ul li a').click(function (e) {

  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $.get(url, function (content) {
    $(this).data('content', content);
  });

  // Prevent the anchor's default click action
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And view the content like:

```
$('.nav ul li a').each(function () {

  // Open the console to view the content
  console.log($(this).data('content'));
});
```